# Flow defined by ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Recall the phase portrait of the linear system $\dot{x}=Ax$
with $A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & -3 \\
  0 & 2  
 \end{pmatrix}
$
Describe $\phi_{t}(N_{\epsilon}(x_0))$
 for $x_0=(-3,0)$ , $\epsilon=.2$ where $\phi$ denotes the flow map $\phi_{t}=e^{tA}$

---

## Solution so far

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors $\lambda_{1}=2$, $\lambda_{2}=-1$, $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 
  & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}$, and $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 
  & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$
$\implies \phi_{t}(N_\epsilon(x_0))= \begin{pmatrix}
  e^{2t} & 0 \\
  0 & e^{-t}  
 \end{pmatrix}x$
I am not understanding how to describe the flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow is not what you wrote but instead
$$
\phi_t=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} e^{-t} & 0\\0 & e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} e^{-t} & e^{-t}-e^{2t}\\0 & e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The rest will come from your computations.

Comment: Are you missing the inverse symbol @Jonas

Comment: It is fine, but the inverse is itself.